# allow non-root user to run programs compiled by root in /root/bin

Tags: centos, compiling, non-root-user, ffmpeg, access-control

I just finished and installed ffmpeg installation on a centOS box via the guide made by ffmpeg themselves https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos As it turns out, `ffmpeg` was installed at `/root/bin` which, if I understand this correctly, is a `root-only` path.

But the thing is, the program is still needed to be run by other users (non-root user that needs to run rTorrent)

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you consider recompiling with different prefixes so that it installs to a common & accessible location, such as /usr/local, instead of trying to change /root's permissions. Also, does centos provide a packaged version of ffmpeg that works for you?

Comment: Don't build software as root, and don't grant access to `root`'s home directory to other users.  Install your software somewhere else (`/usr/local`, or `/opt/ffmpeg`, or whatever), and make sure *that* directory has appropriate permissions.

Comment: @JeffSchaller the default package from `yum` does not give a complete configuration i need. so recompile it is. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just copy files: ffmpeg, ffprobe, ffserver, lame, vsyasm, x264, yasm, ytasm from "/root/bin" to "/usr/bin".
It works in CentOS 6.8.

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through the same process using the same script. I don't understand why they defaulted to building under `/root` in the docs.

Anyway here's an updated script I found with some mods to allow you to specify the build and binary directories...
https://github.com/benbradley/bashbits/blob/master/ffmpeg_build_el.sh

It will build under `/usr/local/src/` and place the resulting binaries in `/usr/local/bin`

I also did the following to make `libmp3lame.so` available before building ffmpeg...

```
cd /usr/local/src
# wget lame source
tar -xzvf lame-3.99.5.tar.gz
cd lame-3.99.5
./configure
make && make install

ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```